# Serialise and deserialise pandas periodIndex series

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, serialization

The pandas `Series.to_json()` function is creating unreadable JSON when using a PeriodIndex.
The error that occurs is:
`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ':' delimiter: line 1 column 5 (char 4)`

I've tried changing the orient, but in all of these combinations of serialising and deserialising the index is lost.

```py
idx = pd.PeriodIndex(['2019', '2020'], freq='A')
series = pd.Series([1, 2], index=idx)
json_series = series.to_json() # This is a demo - in reality I'm storing this in a database, but this code throws the same error
value = json.loads(json_series)
```

[A link to the pandas to_json docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_json.html)
[A link to the python json lib docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

The reason I'm not using json.dumps is that the pandas series object is not serialisable.

Python 3.7.3 Pandas 0.24.2

Comment: related: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25513

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to convert `PeriodIndex` to regular `Index` before dump and convert it back to `PeriodIndex` after load:

```py
regular_idx = period_idx.astype(str)
# then dump
```

```py
# after load
period_idx = pd.to_datetime(regular_idx).to_period()
```